Subsite cannot be found using correct subsite ID, despite the fact that the subsite exists, using Microsoft Graph
I have an application that reads files from a subsite on Sharepoint. Application permissions are being used, and those permissions have been applied to the SiteId. Below is the relevant portion of the code:
DriveCollectionResponse docLibraries = await _graphHelper.GetBaseDocumentLibraryAsync(siteId, subSiteID);

string mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

string mimeTypeXlsm = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12";

//Get the documents rood folder
Drive documentsFolder = docLibraries.Value.Where(x => x.DriveType == "documentLibrary" && x.Name == "Documents").FirstOrDefault();

List<DriveItem> documentsChildren = await _graphHelper.GetChildrenAsync(documentsFolder.Id);
DriveItem estimating03 = documentsChildren.Where(x => x.Name == "04 - Change Management").FirstOrDefault();

The first line is where it fails. If I remove the subsiteId, which is optional, it works, but the correct directory structure is not shown. If I run it as is, I get an error that reads "Requested site cannot be found". This code worked about 3 months ago, the last time it was used. So, I don't understand how this happened.
When you apply the permissions to the siteId, do you also need to apply them to the subsiteId?
I don't think it's a permissions issue, because I would think I would get an access denied error instead.
